# $_POST is empty, form

Tags: php, html

`$_POST` is empty before form, I don't know why.

```
        <form method = "POST">
        <div class = "formDiv">
            <label for="name">name</label>
            <input class="name" id="name">
        </div>
        <div class = "button1">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `before form`? Before submitting? You shouldn't have spaces between the attribute, `=`, and value.

Comment: First of all, your syntax is wrong. There should not be whitespace between tag attributes, the equal sign and the attribute values. Second, you need to add and set the name attribute to your form input tag. That name will be the key to the $_POST array index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your fields require name attribute

```
   <form method = "POST">
        <div class = "formDiv">
            <label for="name">name</label>
            <input name ="name" class="name" id="name">
        </div>
        <div class = "button1">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
```